# What is the right parameter syntax for PyRAF biassec?

Tags: iraf

If I use `epar ccdproc` in `imred >> ccdred >> ccdproc`, I can put `[261:280,1:1032]` in `biassec`, which is in a old iraf code by my teacher:

```
ccdproc @list.all o//@list.all ccdtype='' overscan+ biassec=[261:280,1:1032]
```

But if I use the terminal, it will say:

```
SyntaxError: Too many positional parameters for task ccdproc
```

And if I put `(261:280,1:1032)`, `(261:280;1:1032)` or `(261:280 1:1032)`, it will also pop out `SyntaxError`. It seems that pyraf syntax is slightly different from iraf. What is the right parameter syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, `"[261:280,1:1032]"`.

**Add quotation marks**

```
ccdproc @list.all o//@list.all ccdtype='' overscan+ biassec="[261:280,1:1032]"
```